# How to record a RTSP stream to disk using net7mma?

Tags: c#, rtsp

Running into a little bit of confusion with the [net7mma library](https://net7mma.codeplex.com/).

I want to establish a constant RTSP stream to an Axis IP camera, and then at a certain point, record the RTSP stream to disk. The first should be possible, not sure if the latter can be done within this library or just by piecing together frame images.

Currently trying the following code to receive the stream:

```
        RtspClient client = new RtspClient("rtsp://axiscamera/axis-media/media.amp", RtspClient.ClientProtocolType.Http);
        client.Credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("root", "password");
        client.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
        client.StartPlaying();
        client.Client.RtpPacketReceieved += OnPacketReceived;
```

... but this crashes spectacularly:

> Exception thrown: 'Media.Common.TaggedException`1' in Media.Rtsp.dll
>   The program '[17464] RtspTestViewer.vshost.exe' has exited with code
>   -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Not sure if I'm supposed to be working with `RtspSource` or `RtspClient` or both. How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: I seemed to have lost you here or something, let me know how I can help!

Answer (score 0):

First, Thanks for your interest in the project.

The access violation is probably because there is something already taking exclusive ownership of port 554, sometimes `wmpnetwork.exe` uses port 554 to support the DLNA protocol but it's hard to say without more information, you can use `netstat` to determine what is using that port already.

It surely is possible to save the individual streams but the library doesn't mux (combine) streams into a container yet [even though it can read almost all containers].

The SessionDescription which is retrieved via `SETUP` will tell you what media tracks are available and what codec they utilize.

You will then have to depacketize received data (RtpPackets / RtpFrame) to do anything meaningful with it, e.g. store it to disk or play it back.

`RtpPackets` make up a `RtpFrame`; in most scenarios they consist of a number of packets where the last packet has the `Marker` bit set. Usually all packets which correspond to a `RtpFrame` also share the same `Timestamp` field.

The base `RtpFrame` implementation in my project is just used for events, there should be a derived implementation for your codec within the `RtspServer` class.

Therefore I would use the `OnFrameChanged` event, it fires every time a `RtpPacket` is added to a frame. The parameter 'final' on the `RtpFrameChanged` event indicates if that will be the last time the event will fire with the given frame instance as an argument.

You can usually use some code like follows in the OnRtpFrameChanged event to do the processing.

```
if(final) { /* process the frame further*/ }
```

The derived `RtpFrame` implementation's are useful to depacketize (go from `RtpPackets` to decoder or otherwise) or packetize (go from data to `RtpPackets`).

If you check the `UnitTests` solution you will see how I use the derived implementations for JPEG, H.264 and AAC (maybe also a few others)

If you have a codec which you find is not supported make an issue on the project's [Discussion Area](http://net7mma.codeplex.com/discussions) and we can go from there.

Comment: Trying to follow you here, I didn't think I'd have to create or bring in a separate decoder; essentially RtspSource has an event that fires with a frame of System.Drawing.Image - this is great and gets me most of the way there, but not clear on how to get to that point.

Comment: How do you plan to do anything with the data without a decoder? For example with JPEG there is an implementation which already exists, if your using a Video codec and not an Image then you need a way to get a System.Drawing.Image instance for the format...

Comment: You can also optionally use the RtpTools implementations to write a RtpDump file, that doesn't require any other libraries but I am not sure how useful you will find it as you will still need a Decoder to display the data or hear the audio related.

Comment: I have recently added some code which may assist you in decoding JPEG or H264 so you don't have to 'Bring in another decoder'. There is still work to be done if you want to put the data into a container file which can be played elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Jay, ultimately I ended up using ffmpeg, but would love to revisit a completely managed solution if/when this library gets to the point that it can save the stream to disk for playback in some form. :)

Comment: RtpTools is some form; several; If you can clarify or specify the specific format you require I may be able to look into adding such especially if your willing to provide feedback on the library.

Comment: My 2 dream scenarios would be: 1) Record to disk as H.264/MP4, and 2) receive frame events as Image/Bitmaps for display on UI.

Comment: Receive frame events as Image / Bitmaps on UI seems a little far fetched; almost naive; Recording to disk as H264 is basically done already; mP4 is slightly more work; If you need more advanced scenarios e.g. multiple streams et RCDO or similar than that is also possible but you need to clarify. You originally wanted a `Decoder` and I provided several;

Comment: Wow, this seems super complicated. I feel like this conversation is zoomed in so far that I can see quarks. Is there example code somewhere? :)

Comment: Examples are in the UnitTests solution there are also several examples available on the project site.